# On the definition of maximal invariant

Tags: mathematical-statistics, definition, invariance

On page 184 of *Statistical Models* by A. C. Davison, he states that

> It (an invariant $a(Y)$) is *maximal invariant* if every other invariant statistic is a function of it, **or equivalently**,
>   $$a(y) = a(y') \text{ implies that } y' = g(y) \text{ for some } g \in \mathcal{G}. \tag{1}$$

A little more background: here the topic is about group transformation models. $\mathcal{G}$ is the group of actions on the sample space $\mathcal{Y}$. A statistic $B = b(Y)$ is said to be *invariant* if $b(y) = b(g(y))$ for every $g \in \mathcal{G}$.

I understand that condition $(1)$ implies that "every other invariant statistic is a function of it", but have difficulty in proving the other direction. I also checked several other references (e.g., Theorem 2.3 in *Group Invariance Applications in Statistics* by M. Eaton) and found that only the direction that I understood is mentioned. So my question is, is the statement by Davison really an equivalence (or just half direction is true)? If it is, how to prove "every other invariant statistic is a function of it" implies $(1)$?

Comment: The invariant statistics are really functions of the quotient $Y/G$ and any maximal invariant statistic is just a bijection between $Y/G$ and a subset of $\mathbb{R}.$  If this terminology is unfamiliar, then you might enjoy reading a little about [group actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)).

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I am aware of what you commented. But it may not help solve my question, right? Could you please kindly sketch a proof for my question, if you think the implication is true?

Comment: That was a sketch!

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the bell ring! I think I got it now.

Comment: There is the book _Principles of Statistical Inference_ by Pace, Salvan which plausibly dealt with it  as one acquaintance told me. But unfortunately, neither I have the physical copy in my library nor it is found online. Just nowhere. If you have the copy, please have a look.

Comment: @User1865345 Thank you for your comment.  Later I realized this is just about the understanding of basic invariance concepts and manipulation of notations.  I have added an answer to the OP for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a(y) = a(y')$ but $y'$ cannot be expressed as a transformation of $y$ for any $g \in \mathcal{G}$.  In other words, the equivalence class $[y']$ that $y'$ belongs (aka, the "orbit") and the equivalence class $[y]$ that $y$ belongs are disjoint, which allows us to choose an invariant $b^*$ such that
\begin{align}
b^*(y) \neq b^*(y').
\end{align}
By condition, $b^*$ is a function of the maximal invariant $a$, i.e., $b^* = f(a)$ for some function $f$, but this then leads to contradiction:
\begin{align*}
b^*(y) = f(a(y)) = f(a(y')) = b^*(y'). 
\end{align*}

Therefore, $a(y) = a(y')$ must imply that $y' = g(y)$ for some $g \in \mathcal{G}$.  This proves the other direction of the equivalence.